# how to reset/restore/show the default border/appearance of an input element

Tags: html, css

How would you reset/restore/show the default border/appearance of a text `<input>` element
which has inherited some other border style, which you cannot access and change:

```
input[type="text"] {
   border: 2px dotted #eee;
}
```

Isn't there something like `border: default;` ?

Unfortunately neither `border: initial` nor `border: medium none;` seem to restore the default values.
At least not in chrome 35...

http://jsfiddle.net/e37bh/

Comment: try `border: medium none;`

Comment: thanks, but this does not seem to restore the default appearance

Comment: check the element with Developer tools, perhaps another rule overrides that rule, I added a new inline rule http://prntscr.com/3redgt, and it seems to be working on the Fiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that seems to do the trick is...

```
border-style: inset;
border-color: initial;
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/e37bh/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
border: initial;
```

Displays the border with the browser default styling. I think it should do the trick for you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to reset the border values to default : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/5fC5w/